# Custom constructor Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I started taking some tutorials and some books about `NodeJS`, and started to test out stuff using `Mongoose` and Rest API requests.

The problem that I encountered is related to the creation of a constructor which will take a parameter (requestBody) and then implement the whole binding on the module (on my case `user.js`). That is to make the code more reusable and the user module to handle the bindings not the server module which will increase the source code a lot there.

### Example

The code below is working as it should, but it's not efficient

```
var express = require('express')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , expressValidator = require('express-validator')
    , mongoose = require('mongoose');

var router = express.Router();

router.route('/users')
    // Create a user (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/users)
    .post(function (req, res) {
        // Bind user (repeating the same procedure for every User object)
        var user = new User();
        user.info.name = req.info.name;
        user.info.surname = req.info.name;
        .... // around 10 other properties
        req.info.birthday = req.info.name;

        // Save
        user.save(function (err) {
            .... // Handling completion
        });
    })
```

### My approach

```
// app/models/user.js

var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    info: {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        surname: {type: String, required: true},
        ......
        birthday: {type: String, required: true}, // dd/mm/yyyy
    },
    likes: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    dislikes: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});

function initUser(model) {
    userSchema.info.name = model.info.name;
    userSchema.info.surname = model.info.surname;
    ......
    userSchema.info.birthday = model.info.birthday;
    userSchema.likes = model.likes;
    userSchema.dislikes = model.dislikes;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports.initUser = initUser;
```

Based on this code, on the request I could easily use (Javascript beginner so explanation will be great)

```
var user = new User();
user.initUser(req);
```

but I come up with a really long error which causes the server to crash and the cleanest message is:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

### Questions

Is there anyone who has solved this? I also took a look at [Mongoose site](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/), but there doesn't seem to have a specific thing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your circular json problem, but your initial problem is the way in which you are reading your model properties off your request.

If you post values to that endpoint, the json values you are looking for are going to be on the body property on the request. Pass your function this:

```
user.initUser(req.body)
```

You'll need to install a body parser in express to handle the value properly. Once you've done that and pass in request.body, your approach will work.

Pro tip: don't bother mapping the properties individually. If the keys are correctly named just use them to construct your model directly.

Comment: I already have a body-parser included, that's why I am setting the request directly there. (Forgot to include it on the answer though) On the Example section of answer the code is working OK, but I just want to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Regarding your expert note: When I create the userObject, it has automatically some inherited values like _id and other stuff which I might need, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Thank you for your response, now I get it. I will use the shortcut to send the data formatted the same as the model, so I just bind it directly :)

Comment: _I'd will be auto assigned. Glad I could help.